# Browser sessions not cleared-up when testing two cucumber features

Tags: session, ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I have two cucumber features on my app that resembles something like:

```
Feature: Number 1  
  Background: User logs in on twitter  
    Steps  
  @log-out-remote-too
  Scenario: User logs out from local-app
    Steps  

Feature: Number 2  
  Scenario: User is logged in and is welcomed  
     Sees "welcome" inside "something"  
     Sees more stuff
```

I am using webdriver/selenium for firefox and the css selector. The second feature always! fails, no matter what. 
I have tried removing the hook so it does not go to twitter.com and logs out. 
I have tried also a hook @re-login for logging in on my local app.
I have also tried clearing the cookies through Capybara.

I would really thank if someone could help me on this. I am resisting the idea to develop my app without following the outside-in cycle but have not so much time.

PD I have noticed that the presence of the second feature (even if it has no scenarios on it) makes the first feature fail. This is weird to me

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a workaround for this.

I wrote the following hook:

```
Before('@with_remote_login') do
  Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
end
```

which I added to the scenarios which needed to run "cleanly"

```
Feature: Number 1  
  Background: User logs in on twitter  
    Steps  

  Scenario: User logs out from local-app
    Steps  

Feature: Number 2 
  @with_remote_login
  Scenario: User is logged in and is welcomed  
     Sees "welcome" inside "something"  
     Sees more stuff
```